# Geometry Question with irregular hexagons

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Suppose you have a rectangle with sides $x$ and $y$ and both numbers are integers and have no factors. now draw lines inside this rectangle starting with a line at $45^\circ$ coming out of a corner and every time a side of the rectangle is hit, the line is reflected inward. Eventually this line hits another one of the corners after $(x+y-2)$ reflections.

Now suppose you have a hexagon with 5 right angles and an angle of $270^\circ$. Instead of one equation to find the number of reflections, surely now there must be 3 different amounts of reflections depending on which corner you start at since the shape is now asymmetric and has three pairs of corners.

Assuming every length is again both an integer and are all co-prime, are there equations which you could use to find the 3 amounts of reflections? It seems to me that there should be because every instance of this that I've tried has had some patterns: eg. The 2 lower numbers always add up to the larger number minus 2

Hopefully this is phrased well enough to be understood

Comment: what do you mean by "and have no factors" isn't $n$ a factor of $n$?

Comment: I meant that they should have no common factors that are integers

Comment: What happens when a ray passes by the 270° angle in such a way that it coincides with the wall in just a single point? Will it hit the wall, ending its course, or will it be reflected, or will it continue past that single point? In the first of these three cases, you'd have to count that corner thrice, so you might have even more pairs of connected corners.

Comment: “allo coprime”: I don't see how that can be possible. The long horizontal length is the sum of the two short horizontal lengths, and the same for the vertical ones. If all short lengths are odd, then both long edges will be even and thus share a factor. If one short edge is even, then the long edge in the orthogonal direction will be even as well. I can think of no configuration where all six lengths would be coprime.

Comment: I've phrased this badly. I mean all 6 sides have no common factors.